# No network connection after upgrading Ubuntu to 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 18.04, dhclient

I have been trying to find a solution to my issue for three days now. Since the upgrade to 18.04, I cannot access the network, neither through cable nor WiFi.

I've tried different solutions from forums, but I'm stuck at the same status. The network is detected by the computer, but when I click on connect, the connection fails during the step "network address definition".

When I try to restart the network connection with these commands:

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up
sudo dhclient enp2s0
```

I get a *segfault*.

I cannot ping `8.8.8.8`.

Any idea on how to fix this?